# capturing the usernames after List: tag

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list named "userlist" with all the usernames listed beside "List:",
my idea is to parse the line with "List:" and then split based on  "," and put them in a list,
however am not able to capture the line ,any inputs on how can this be achieved?

```
output="""             alias: tech.sw.host
             name: tech.sw.host
            email: tech.sw.host
           email2: tech.sw.amss
             type: email list
   look_elsewhere: /usr/local/mailing-lists/tech.sw.host
             text: List tech SW team
  list_supervisor: <username>
             List: username1,username2,username3,username4,
                 : username5
          Members: User1,User2,
                 : User3,User4,
                 : User5 """
#print output
userlist = []
for line in output :
    if "List" in line:
        print line
```

Comment: You should split output at each newline-character first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `regex`, `str.translate` and `str.split` :

```
>>> import re
>>> from string import whitespace
>>> strs = re.search(r'List:(.*)(\s\S*\w+):', ph, re.DOTALL).group(1)
>>> strs.translate(None, ':'+whitespace).split(',')
['username1', 'username2', 'username3', 'username4', 'username5']
```

You can also create a dict here, which will allow you to access any attribute:

```
def func(lis):
    return ''.join(lis).translate(None, ':'+whitespace)

lis = [x.split() for x in re.split(r'(?<=\w):',ph.strip(), re.DOTALL)]
dic = {}
for x, y in zip(lis[:-1], lis[1:-1]):
    dic[x[-1]] = func(y[:-1]).split(',')
dic[lis[-2][-1]] = func(lis[-1]).split(',')

print dic['List']
print dic['Members']
print dic['alias']
```

**Output:**

```
['username1', 'username2', 'username3', 'username4', 'username5']
['User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User4', 'User5']
['tech.sw.host']
```

Comment: thanks,your almost works apart from exclusing any emtpy strings,how do I exclude  any empty stringsl like ''?

Comment: @user2639990 use `filter`: `filter(None, strs.translate(None, ':'+whitespace).split(','))`

Comment: One question..instead of printing the output as a list..is there a way to print only the usernames seperated by comma(,) like 'username1', 'username2', 'username3', 'username4', 'username5'

Comment: @user2639990 just remove the `split(',')` call:  `strs.translate(None, ':'+whitespace)`. In the second code: `dic[x[-1]] = func(y[:-1])`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support..is there a way to filter our multiple entries...we are already filtering empty strings..lets say if I want to filter ',' too...

Comment: @user2639990 If you're getting empty strings then use str.join` after the `filter` call : `','.join(filter(None, strs.translate(None, ':'+whitespace).split(',')))`

Answer (score 3):

If it were me, I'd parse the entire input so as to have easy access to every field:

```
inFile = StringIO.StringIO(ph)
d = collections.defaultdict(list)

for line in inFile:
    line = line.partition(':')
    key = line[0].strip() or key
    d[key] += [part.strip() for part in line[2].split(',')]

print d['List']
```

Comment: Why importing StringIO instead of using `for line in output.splitlines()` ?

Comment: @Rob - Thanks,how to modify the above script to exclude empty strings?

Comment: @BasSwinckels - 1) Because in a production environment, the data probably comes from a file-like object, and 2) because I think in file solutions more often than string solutions.  There's nothing wrong with your suggestion, however.

Comment: @user2639990 - You don't have to make any change. empty strings are already excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for line in output.split("\n"):
    if "List" in line:
        print line
```

When Python is asked to treat a string like a collection, it'll treat each character in that string as a member of that collection (as opposed to each line, which is what you're trying to accomplish).

You can tell this by printing each line:

```
>>> for line in ph:
...     print line
... 

a
l
i
a
s
:

t
e
...
```

By the way, there are far better ways of handling this. I'd recommend taking a look at Python's built-in RegEx library: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using `strip()` to remove the white spaces and line breakers before doing the check:

```
if 'List:' == line.strip()[:5]:
```

this should capture the line you need, then you can extract the usernames using `split(',')`:

```
usernames = [i for i in line[5:].split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two solutions, which are essentially the same, but the first is easier to understand.

```
import re

output = """   ... """

# First solution: join continuation lines, the look for List

# Join lines such as username5 with previous line
#             List: username1,username2,username3,username4,
#                 : username5
# becomes
#             List: username1,username2,username3,username4,username5
lines = re.sub(r',\s*:\s*', ',', output)

for line in lines.splitlines():
    label, values = [token.strip() for token in line.split(':')]
    if label == 'List':
        userlist = userlist = [user.strip() for user in values.split(',')]       
print 'Users:', ', '.join(userlist)


# Second solution, same logic as above
# Different means
tokens, = [line for line in re.sub(r',\s*:\s*', ',', output).splitlines() 
        if 'List:' in line]
label, values = [token.strip() for token in tokens.split(':')]
userlist = userlist = [user.strip() for user in values.split(',')]
print 'Users:', ', '.join(userlist)
```